# Removing duplicate in a column

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
select
v.id,
c.image_type_id,
vp.x, 
vp.y,
vp.z
FROM
v,
vp,
c,
WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
```

I need the v.id to be unique in each column (only one entry for each v.id). Some of the ids are returning multiple rows. 
 What's the best way to do it?

P.S The rows of the duplicate ids are different

Comment: when it repeats.. are the rows actually different? if not, you can use distinct or even group by... you might even be able to make use of a group by concat function.

Comment: If the rows are complete duplicates, then `SELECT DISTINCT` will do it.  If they are not complete duplicates, how do you want to choose which one is displayed?

Comment: The rows are different except for the id. I would select the first one for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  to use "group by" note that you will lose some of the values in the other columns

```
select
v.id,
max(c.image_type_id),
max(vp.x), 
max(vp.y),
max(vp.z)
FROM
v,
vp,
c,
WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
group by v.id;
```

Comment: By "lose some of the values" I think you mean that it won't return a coherent row; the columns may be from different rows.

Comment: If I put the query in parentheses 

(select
v.id,
max(c.image_type_id),
max(vp.x), 
max(vp.y),
max(vp.z)
FROM
v,
vp,
c,
WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
group by v.id;) t
It gives me error: missing right parenthesis